# "I was struggling to establish and [to] follow"

Tags: conjunctions, infinitives, parallelism

I am learning English. I found this sentence in a book.

> At the time, I was struggling to establish myself as a writer and to follow my path...

Is it grammatically correct to use the to-infinitive *and*.

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically correct. That's why it's an actual sentence in an actual book. I don't think you understand what "learning" means. You don't acquire a language by going around telling native speakers they are doing it wrong. You do as they do. Then and only then will you actually learn. Perhaps even more to the point, if you don't believe someone who formally studied translation, is paid actual money to do it, and has to put his name on the title page of a physical book, then why would you believe JoeRandom4109 off the Internet who you know nothing about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a correct usage.

What you're doing is omitting the part **[I was struggling]** from the sentence:

> At the time, I was struggling to establish myself as a writer and 
>   **[I was struggling]** to follow my path....

Since repetition would be redundant there, it's supposed to be omitted.